# Windows 8 is not booting

Tags: windows, windows-8, bios

I was working on my Toshiba c650 laptop when it crashed and restarted. Now the computer freezes after the boot menu and does not work until I reboot it and the same thing happens. I tried chkdsk, FixMBR and other utilities but nothing worked. I booted from Hiren's BootCD to a mini XP environment and tried Bellavista (a BCD editor) and it resulted in an error saying that the boot configuration couldn't be loaded. I also tried to repair the computer from the installation CD using the System Restore, Refresh, Reset and Automatic Repair options, and again nothing worked. When I tried to reinstall Windows it said that all the partitions have boot problems and they are not in the BIOS without an error code.

What can I do?